# Why does Dapper Open for Query but not Execute

Tags: dapper

I realize this might simply be a bug or oversight, but I sincerely doubt it:

When I run the following code:

```
using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString)) {
    return cnn.Query<Foo>("select top 15 * from Foo");
}
```

The Dapper Query method opens the connection before it runs anything.

When i run this code:

```
using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString)) {
    cnn.Execute("insert Foo(bar_id, name) values (@bar_id, @name)", fooList);
}
```

The code throws with an InvalidOperationException:

```
ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection.
The connection's current state is closed.
```

It sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628983/why-doesnt-dapper-dot-net-open-and-close-the-connection-itself), but I can't tell if there's some reason why Execute can't be doing the same logic.

My question is why, or if not, should I file a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bug, and pretty sure it is already listed. I have a new year's resolution to clear the backlog so I should get to that soon.